# double pointer memory allocation accessing problem with pointer arithmetic without index

Tags: c

I am trying to use double pointer memory allocation without using index. I am only allowed to use pointer arithmetic to access to address.

```
char** p2 = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char) * 2);
*p2 = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 3);


**p2 = 's';
printf("%c\n", **p2);
printf("%p\n", **p2);
printf("%c\n", p2[0][0]);
printf("%p\n\n", p2[0][0]);

(**p2)++;
**p2 = 'k';
printf("%c\n", **p2);
printf("%p\n", **p2);
printf("%c\n", p2[0][1]);
printf("%p\n\n", p2[0][1]);

After fail above code,

int* ptr = *p2;
*ptr = 'h';
printf("%c\n", *ptr);
printf("%i\n", *ptr);
printf("%c\n", p2[0][0]);
printf("%i\n\n", p2[0][0]);

(*ptr)++;
*ptr = 'a';
printf("%c\n", *ptr);
printf("%i\n", *ptr);
printf("%c\n", p2[0][1]);
printf("%i\n\n", p2[0][1]);
```

this one also did not work.

So, I was able to access til p2[0][0], returning s and 0x73.

However, when I tried to access to next index using pointer arithmetic (**p++), **p2 value and p2[0][1] are different.

What pointer arithmetic should I use to access p2[0][1] and more?

Comment: Your frst problem is you allocate 2 chars not 2 char*s so you have undefined behavior at line 2.

Comment: You also don't want to deference your pointer before you increment; `(**ptr)++`. You are trying to access the next place in memory, so you want to increment the address: `ptr++`. But your other one is ok: `(*ptr)++`

Comment: `char **p2 = malloc (sizeof *p2 * 2);` then `*p2 = malloc (sizeof **p2 * 3);` (or better `p2[0] = malloc (sizeof **p2 * 3);`) There is no need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Comment: @John3136 I changed to char** p2 = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char* ) * 2); to allocate 2char*s. However, still no able to access to p2[0][1]

Comment: `(**p2)++;` makes `'s'`, `'t'`, it doesn't advance the pointer, then you overwrite `'t'` with `'k'` doing `**p2 = 'k';`.

Comment: This code is loaded with guesses, most of them bad. Do you know what `**p2` is *doing*? And if not, perhaps that's part of the problem. But if you *do* understand, you'll also understand why `printf("%p\n", **p2);` make no sense. `**p2` evaluates to a `char`. A `char` is not a pointer, and thus `%p` as the format specifier makes no sense.

Comment: This should immediately raise a red flag:  `char** p2 = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char) * 2);`  So `p2` is a pointer to a pointer to a `char`, so you need to allocate `sizeof(char *)` times however many instances you want (presumably 2).  But you're using `sizeof(char)` instead, which is probably only 1/4 or 1/8 the size of what you need.

Comment: Related: [Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pointers are relatively straight forward, but in your case it looks like you are having difficulty understanding *"What is my pointer?"* Reading between the tea leaves a bit further, it looks like your primary confusion surround *"What do it do with the* `'*'`*s?"*

Let's take a step back, and recall that a pointer is simply a normal variable that holds the address of something else as its value. (i.e. it *points* to where something else is stored in memory). While you normally think of `int a = 5;` where `a` itself holds `5` as its value, a pointer, `int *b = &a;` holds (points to) the address of `a` as its value (i.e. `b` points to the address in memory where `5` is stored).

Now let's think about how we keep the declarations and use of pointers straight. When  you declare a pointer, e.g. `char **p2;`, you have declared a *pointer-to-pointer-to* `char`. So when you think about what it is you can assign to `p2`, you simply answer the questions (1) What is my pointer? (`p2` is a *pointer-to:* what? *pointer-to* `char`) and (2) What *type* of address does it store as its value? (`p2` holds a *pointer-to* `char`) as its value.

When you declared `p2` and attempted to allocate storage, what type did you use? `sizeof(char)`. It should be clear now that `p2` doesn't hold the address of `char` as its value, it holds the address of a *pointer-to* `char` as its value, e.g. `(char*)`.

The way to get this right every time is to use the *dereferenced pointer* as your *type-size* rather than trying to use a basic type `char, short, int, etc..` and then add `'*'`s to it hoping to get it right. Since you both declare and initialize with a call to `malloc` in one-shot, you mask the simplicity by having the `**` part of the  declaration in the same line as your allocation. Instead think of it this way to sort it out in your mind to begin with.

```
char **p2;                      /* declare a pointer-to-pointer-char */
p2 = malloc (sizeof *p2 * 2);   /* use the dereferenced pointer to set typesize */
```

`p2` is your pointer, so `*p2` sets your typesize. (e.g. `p2` is a *pointer-to-pointer-to* `char`), so when you dereference it (i.e. remove one-level of indirection), you are left with a *pointer-to* `char`). Which is what you are needing to allocate (pointers). So `sizeof *p2 * 2` allocates a block of memory large enough to store two pointers to `char`. There is no guessing about how many `'*'`s you add to `char`, you just use the dereferenced pointer -- and the compiler automatically knows how much storage the type requires. Then `p2 = malloc ....` assigns the starting address for that block of memory to `p2`.

(**note:** you must **validate** that the call to `malloc` succeeded by checking the return, e.g. `if (p2 == NULL)` the allocation failed.)

That is basically it. The typesize controls pointer arithmetic. So if you have a pointer to `char`, (say `char *p;`), `p++;` advances the pointer by 1-byte, to the next *character*. If you have a pointer to `int`, (say `int *pi;`), then `pi++;` advances the pointer by 4-bytes so it is pointing to the next *integer*.

With that as the background, what it looks like you are attempting to do is something like the following short example. (note: I have changed the output format to make it read easier)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void) {

    /* don't cast the return of malloc, 
     * use dereferenced pointer as typesize.
     * allocates 2 pointers, p2[0], p2[1] - unused.
     */
    char **p2 = malloc (sizeof *p2 * 2);
    if (!p2) {      /* validate every allocation */
        perror ("malloc-p2");
        return 1;
    }
    /* use p2[0] instead of *(p2 + 0), i.e. *p2
     * allocates 3-chars of storage, assigns starting address to p2[0].
     */
    p2[0] = malloc (sizeof *p2[0] * 3);
    if (!p2[0]) {   /* ditto */
        perror ("malloc-p2[0]");
        return 1;
    }

    **p2 = 's';     /* assigns 's' to first char of first pointer */

    /* you can't advance p2 or you lose your original pointer (memory-leak) */
    char *ptmp = p2[0];     /* use a temp pointer instead to 1st 3-chars */
    ptmp++;                 /* advance the temp pointer */
    *ptmp = 'k';            /* assign 'k' as 2nd char */

    printf (" p2  (%p)\n  %c  (%p)\n  %c  (%p)\n",
            (void*)p2, p2[0][0], (void*)&p2[0][0], p2[0][1], (void*)&p2[0][1]);

    free (p2[0]);   /* free storage  */
    free (p2);      /* free pointers */
}
```

(**note:** the address of `p2` cannot be changed. If you assign something else to `p2` or advance `p2++;` it no longer points to the start of your allocated memory block, so (unless you save a copy of the pointer) the block of memory can no longer be freed resulting in a *memory-leak*.)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/ptr2ptrfun
 p2  (0x73a010)
  s  (0x73a030)
  k  (0x73a031)
```

You see above `p2` is the pointer to the block of memory for 2-pointers, `0x73a010`, while the address where `'s'` and `'k'` are stored are sequential and within the storage for 3-characters created by the second call to `malloc` with the starting address assigned to the first pointer allocated (the second pointer you allocate remains unused)

**Memory Use/Error Check**

In any code you write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed.

It is imperative that you use a memory error checking program to insure you do not attempt to access memory or write beyond/outside the bounds of your allocated block, attempt to read or base a conditional jump on an uninitialized value, and finally, to confirm that you free all the memory you have allocated.

For Linux `valgrind` is the normal choice. There are similar memory checkers for every platform. They are all simple to use, just run your program through it.

```
$  valgrind ./bin/ptr2ptrfun
==8767== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==8767== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==8767== Using Valgrind-3.12.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==8767== Command: ./bin/ptr2ptrfun
==8767== 
 p2  (0x51db040)
  s  (0x51db090)
  k  (0x51db091)
==8767== 
==8767== HEAP SUMMARY:
==8767==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8767==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 2 frees, 19 bytes allocated
==8767== 
==8767== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==8767== 
==8767== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==8767== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Always confirm that you have freed all memory you have allocated and that there are no memory errors.

That's pointers in a nutshell. Let me know if you have any further questions.